# Spring Data and stored procedures

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a stored procedure with the following declaration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAttributesForCategory(IN catId BIGINT(20))
```

In my **Spring Boot**-backed app there is an entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = "ProductAttribute.getAttributesForCategory",
                procedureName = "GetAttributesForCategory",
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "catId", 
                                                    type = Long.class, 
                                                    mode = ParameterMode.IN)
                }
        )
})
public class ProductAttribute {
    ...
}
```

And the correspondent repository looks like:

```
public interface ProductAttributeReposirory extends JpaRepository<ProductAttribute, Long> {

    @Procedure(name = "getAttributesForCategory")
    List<ProductAttribute> getAttributesForCategory(@Param("catId") Long catId);
}
```

All is made according to [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/jpa21), but an exception is occurred during Spring context loading:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'productAttributeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: 
No property getAttributesForCategory found for type ProductAttribute!
```

I can't imagine what goes wrong. Anybody can?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with this, and resolved it by adding an OUT @StoredProcedureParameter:

`@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "inVar", type = String.class),
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "outVar", type = ArrayList.class)`

though at this point I'm getting a different error "Parameter index of 2 is out of range"